# Consulta Mysql con varias condiciones de 2 campos

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo una consulta que estoy realizando en mysql, el problema es que no se esta cumpliendo la condicion de ALMACEN_REP ya que tendria que traer todo lo que tiene 'BM' junto con la siguiente condicion TIPO como se ve en el ejemplo

```
SELECT * FROM transformadores
where (ALMACEN_REP  = 'BM') AND (TIPO = 'TND') OR  (TIPO = 'TNE') OR  (TIPO = 'TNM') OR
(TIPO = 'TNP') OR  (TIPO = 'TNS') OR  (TIPO = 'TNZ') OR
(TIPO = 'TUE')   order by ID desc;
```

Comment: datos de prueba y salida esperada, por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sin más datos aportados y suponiendo que quieres mostrar el listado de tipos de transformadores de esa lista que estén en el 'BM', prueba con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM transformadores
where (ALMACEN_REP = 'BM') AND (TIPO = 'TND' OR TIPO = 'TNE' OR TIPO = 'TNM' OR TIPO = 'TNP' OR TIPO = 'TNS' OR TIPO = 'TNZ' OR TIPO = 'TUE') order by ID desc;
```

Comment: Hola hice algo asi SELECT * FROM transformadores
        where (ALMACEN_REP  = 'BM') AND (TIPO IN('TND','TNE','TNM','TNP','TNS','TNZ','TUE'))    order by ID desc;